# How to model polymorphic data in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

We have some data that we'd like to model in the following way. We have two fields:

- to
- from

and each of those fields have the following data:

- some enum
- some foreign key (one of 4 possible tables)

Does PostgreSQL provide a way to store this polymorphic enum + dynamic foreign key?

Comment: Why not define 4 nullable fk columns only one of which has a value for a given row?

Comment: Would there have to be 8 nullable fk columns, 4 for `to` and 4 for `from`?

Comment: Yes, there would have to be one fk constraint for each relationship. Declarative constraints really should be preferred. Precludes many problems. Star schema?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use json (or jsonb or array) for store 2 fields in "from" and "to" columns.

Then you can use generated columns to store one fk for each table.

Something like this:

```
create table table1 (
  id serial primary key,
  name text
);
insert into table1 values (1,'one'),(2,'two');

create table table2 (
  id serial primary key,
  name text
);
insert into table2 values (1,'one'),(2,'two');

create table the_table(
  "from" jsonb,
  from1 bigint generated always as (case when "from"->>'enum' = '1' then ("from"->>'data')::bigint else null end) stored,
  from2 bigint generated always as (case when "from"->>'enum' = '2' then ("from"->>'data')::bigint else null end) stored,
  foreign key (from1) references table1 (id),
  foreign key (from2) references table2 (id)
);

insert into the_table("from") values ('{"enum":1, "data":2}');
```